# Qt наследование и parent

Tags: c++, qt

Всем привет. Ни для кого не секрет, что в чистых плюсах объекты уничтожаются в обратном порядке созданию.
Если у нас есть базовый класс А и производный от него В, то при создании класса В - сначала инициализируется конструктор базового класса, а потом производного. При уничтожении класса В сначала уничтожится класс В потом базовый.

Меня интересует порядок уничтожения в Qt при наследовании и объявлении parent
допустим у нас есть код

заголовочник

```
class list : public QAbstractListModel
{
...
  explicit list( QObject* parent ) noexcept;
...
}
```

сипипишник

```
...
list::list( QObject* parent ) noexcept
 : QAbstractListModel( parent )
{
}
...
```

и так, где то мы создаем наш list

```
list* list = new list( some_parent );
```

сначала будет создан базовый класс, потом наследник.

Когда объекты начнут уничтожатся наш лист будет уничтожен благодаря parent который мы указали в аргументах конструктора. Правильно ли я понимаю, что порядок уничтожения будет прямой, сначала базовый класс, а потом уже производный( так как parent передан базовому классу )?

Comment: Наоборот, сначала родитель уничтожит детей, потом себя. Список детей есть в https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#children

Comment: Откровенно смутило вот это - When any QObject in the tree is deleted, if the object has a parent, the destructor automatically removes the object from its parent. If the object has children, the destructor automatically deletes each child. Отсюда я сделал вывод что первый родитель, а потом дети

Comment: `some_parent` точно так же унаследован от QObject'а... так вот, все потомки будут истреблены в деструторе QObject'а... считать, что это «до», «после» или «во время», пожалуй, зависит от мировозрения, но ИМХО ближе вариант «после»...

Comment: @Slav9n92, у любого дерева при _запросе на удаление_ узла узел рекурсивно удаляет дочерние элементы. То есть собственно процесс удаления начинается с листьев дерева.